# Android: Progress bar not showing intermediate states

Tags: android, multithreading, progress-bar

There are other similar SO questions but none really helped.

I just want to implement a progress bar, that on button click, starts from 0, moves gradually and stops at a point (which is read from sharedPreferences).

However things are working but that progress bar is not gradually updating , instead it appears straight at the end point.

A simplified code I'm pasting here:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

int primaryProgress = 0;
int finalPrimaryProgress = 60;
ProgressBar progressBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
    progressBar.setMax(100);
    progressBar.setProgress(0);
}

public void click(View view) {

    while (primaryProgress < finalPrimaryProgress)
    {
        progressBar.setProgress(primaryProgress+=1);
        Thread.sleep(100); //This is inside Try-catch in actual code.
    }
}
}
```

I know the problem is with Threads, but I am not too friendly with threads so unable to understand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your "click" method is happening on the UI thread (otherwise, you'd probably get an exception when you try to alter the view on a background thread).

Think about what you're doing here - the moment you click a button, you begin a loop. On each iteration of the loop, you change the value of the progress bar, and then make the (main) thread sleep for 100ms, then repeat.

Problem is, you're never letting the runtime react to what change you made. Once you change a value of a view (for instance, change the text of a TextView), the Android runtime needs to have time to react to your change, adjusting the view's size, position and then redraw. Your code basically blocks anything from happening before you change the value again, because you're telling the main thread to sleep, and then you immediately change the value again.

The expected result here would be seeing the progress bar drawn in its final state once you stopped changing its value without letting the runtime actually do anything with it.

As an alternative to your current click method, try doing something with postDelayed. This will allow the runtime to perform a full measure-layout-draw cycle between every iteration:

```
private void increaseProgressBar()
{
    if (progressBar.getProgress() < progressBar.getMax())
        progressBar.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                progressBar.setProgress(progressBar.getProgress() + 1); // increase the value of the progress bar.
                increaseProgressBar(); // call the function again, but after a delay.
            }
        }, 100);
}

public void click(View v)
{
    increaseProgressBar();
}
```

**Note:** Keep in mind that currently, clicking the button multiple times will cause erratic behaviour, since your basically adding additional runnables to this sequence, causing the progress bar to grow faster. You could defend against such a case fairly easily with a simple flag.

Comment: That not only solved the problem but also cleared all the doubts I had about Thread.sleep() previously. Had I enough reputation, I would have given you some.